# How to cut out a part of a path?

Tags: c#

I want to cut out a part of a `path` but don't know how.
To get the `path`, I use this code:

```
String path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(fullyQualifiedName);
```

**(path = "Y:\Test\Project\bin\Debug")**

Now I need the first part *without* **"\bin\Debug"**.

How can I cut this part out of the current path?

Comment: Do you want to cut a specified number of directory levels, or cut to a certain depth, or cut `\bin\Debug` specifically? What's the rule you're trying to apply?

Comment: Seems you are looking to find the root of your project. This is not good idea to do as when you publish or use your software in real you won't get bin/debug stuff there, so better copy all your files there and and also try to use relative path you find dynamically. like this code  string dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(YOURFULLYQUALIFIEDASSEMBLYNAME)).Location);

Answer (score 18):

If you know, that you don't need only "\bin\Debug" you could use replace:

```
path = path.Replace("\bin\Debug", "");
```

or

```
path = path.Remove(path.IndexOf("\bin\Debug"));
```

If you know, that you don't need everything, after second `\` you could use this:

```
path = path.Remove(path.LastIndexOfAny(new char[] { '\\' }, path.LastIndexOf('\\') - 1));
```

and finally, you could `Take` so many parts, how many you want like this:

```
path = String.Join(@"\", path.Split('\\').Take(3));
```

or `Skip` so many parts, how many you need:

```
path = String.Join(@"\", path.Split('\\').Reverse().Skip(2).Reverse());
```

Comment: Instead of string methods i would use the `Directory` class.

Comment: Sorry, but i don't know how to make it with `Directory` class, but there are at least 5 examples how it could be done with `String` :)

Comment: @FSoul: `Directory.GetParent` returns a `FileInfo` object which has also a `Parent` property if you want to go up the hyrarchy. A `FileInfo` object has a `FullName` property to get it's path. Hope my sample works (could not test it). http://stackoverflow.com/a/17782827/284240 Never use string methods with paths since you are reinventing the wheel and probably prone to errors.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the `Path` class and a subsequent call of the [`Directory.GetParent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getparent.aspx) method:

```
String dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(fullyQualifiedName);
string root = Directory.GetParent(dir).FullName;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it within only 3 lines.

```
String path= @"Y:\\Test\\Project\\bin\\Debug";
String[] extract = Regex.Split(path,"bin");  //split it in bin
String main = extract[0].TrimEnd('\\'); //extract[0] is Y:\\Test\\Project\\ ,so exclude \\ here
Console.WriteLine("Main Path: "+main);//get main path
```

Comment: is it necessary to use the `"\\"` if you already have `"@"` in the beginning of the string? thanks

Comment: ah, thanks, because I thought that the `@` at the beginning interpret the string literally.

Comment: No, it is not necessary. The whole point of prefixing the string with `@` is to create a literal string. That means you don't have to escape backslashes.

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain the path of the parent folder of your path like this:

```
path = Directory.GetParent(path);
```

In your case, you'd have to do it twice.